# Android - Use Fingerprint API in Android API 17

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Recently, Google allowed developers to use Fingerprint API in Android 6.0 (API 23).

I have an android project with `compiledSdkVersion 23` and `minSdkVersion 17`.

My question is: Can i use Fingerprint API in my project, i tried to use Google sample in my project but i have this error message:

```
Class Requires API level 23 (current min is 17)
```

if i can i will be grateful to any one gives me a good tutorial.

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use Support Library v4 to support minSdk less than 23. You have to use class name accordingly e.g. FingerprintManagerCompat, etc.

Check [this github sample](https://github.com/AMykich/Android-Fingerprint-API)